# PHP Select Statment into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to do a two step process (1) select the DB key into an array that (2) will be used to feed another query.

**example**

```
Select ID from file1, file2 where file1.id = file2.id (will yeild 
multiple items) into an array var called $emailList = array();
```

then use the array var $emailList to select data using this sql statement
SELECT id, name, address, phone from file1 where id in ($emailList)
for processing a loop.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have tried, as well as a question / description of the problem.

Comment: i would bet this could be done in one querry

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, you are doing query on the same database right? If so, then why not just use a join statement.

If you don't know it yet, then you can refer to this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for the `IN` clause, as is defined [in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html). So:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       address,
       phone
FROM file1
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT ID
     FROM file1
     INNER JOIN file2
         ON file1.id = file2.id)
```

is valid.